# Вопрос по кастомному View

Tags: android

Есть кастомный View, в методе OnDraw которого я проделываю некоторые операции рисования. Мне нужно реализовать, что бы после некоторых операций содержимое Canvans  как бы сохранялось и оставалось на фоне и последущие изменения в OnDraw рисовались сверху. Как это реализовать?

Comment: например можно использовать два вью одно поверх другого с альфой, если одно то можно реализовать "два слоя" или возможен вариант сделать "скриншот" нарисованого и поставить, как background

Comment: можно нарисовать содержимое canvas на Bitmap, и использовать этот Bitmap

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне эту операцию нужно будет производить много раз. А как такое реализовано в рисовалках?

Comment: А как это вариант. Создать массив, в который добавлять объект с координатами и в OnDraw в цикле их прорисовать.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете в методе onDraw использовать флаг, при отсутствии которого канва не будет перерисовываться. Например, *private boolean _firstDraw;*

```
private void doDraw(Canvas a_canvas){
 if (_firstDraw) {
                _firstDraw = false;
                 _canvas.drawBitmap(_backgroundImage, 0, 0, null); //example
              ... //Set other drawing properties
    }

  ... //do other drawing
}
```

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!